# Получить структуру по указателю полученому как возврат из функции DLL

Tags: python, ctypes

Функция, вызванная из DLL, возвращает указатель на структуру.

Как получить эту структуру и её данные в Python?

```
from ctypes import *

# give location of dll
wsd = cdll.LoadLibrary(".//CoreLib.dll")

class wGuiEvent(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
    ("id", c_int32),
    ("name", c_uint32),
    ("event", c_uint32),
    ]

GUIEvent = wGuiEvent() ???
GUIEvent = wsd.wGuiReadEvent() ???
GUIEvent.event ???
???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала надо определиться с "функцией, вызванной из DLL". Какая именно функция должна возвращать структуру вы не указали, как и используемую библиотеку. Google по запросу "wGuiEvent" привёл меня [сюда](http://worldsim3d.com/Forum/index.php?topic=299.0), от этого и буду отталкиваться в предположениях.

```
wsd = CDLL.LoadLibrary(".//CoreLib.dll")

class wGuiEvent(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("id", c_int32),
        ("name", c_uint32),
        ("event", c_uint32),
    ]

wsd.wGuiReadEvent.restype = POINTER(wGuiEvent)
guiEvent = wsd.wGuiReadEvent()
```